# Running Google auto-complete on AJAX content

Tags: javascript, ajax, autocomplete

My website loads all its content via AJAX, and that includes the address form I am using Google's auto-complete for. The problem is that Google's demo code initiates the listener on input field, even if it doesn't yet exist, which is the case with AJAX.

What I can't figure out is how to transfer the listener event to the actual `autocomplete` form input with perhaps `onkeyup`.

Excuse my crude AJAX substitute in my code example!

```js
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  
var componentForm = {
  route: 'long_name'
};
      
var options = {
  types: ['geocode'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('autocomplete')),options);
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="ajax"></div>

<a href='#' onclick='document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML="<input class=\"form-control\" id=\"autocomplete\" placeholder=\"Enter your address...\" onFocus=\"geolocate()\" type=\"text\"><label for=\"route\"></label><input type=\"text\" id=\"route\" disabled=\"true\">";'>click me</a>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAUn3BBDhG1bXZckXyx6f2E2NSOhasl6FY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Why don't you run that code after it exists?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: That depends on how you create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initAutocomplete function is a callback specified in the Google Maps script URL (as a GET param)

You can do this

```
function initAutocomplete() {
  var el = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
  if(el!=null){
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(el,options);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }
}
```

That means it just won't do anything if the element hasn't been created yet, so you will then need to call initAutocomplete after your AJAX call that creates the element.